# Angular FormBuilder in Pending state when having more than one AsyncValidator

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to add some custom validation to my form in Angular. The problem is that when I have only one AsyncValidator in the form, everything works as expected, so I change one value and form status is changed to `Valid`. While when I have two AsyncValidators, the form stays in `Pending` state until I change both of them.

Here's my code:

uniqueValue.validator.ts

```
export function UniqueValidator(service: ExistsService, originalValue: string = null): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return control => {
        if (control.valueChanges == null) {
            return of(null);
        }

        return control.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(400),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap(value => {
                    if (value === originalValue) {
                        control.markAsPristine();
                        return of(false);
                    }

                    return service.exists(value);
                }),
                map((unique: boolean) => (!unique ? null : { 'notUnique': true })),
                first());
    }
}
```

some-component.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form= this.fb.group({
    email: [this.email,
      [Validators.required],
      UniqueValidator(this.myService)
    ],
    username: [this.userName,
      [Validators.required],
      UniqueValidator(this.myService)
    ],
    fullName: [this.fullName]
  });

  this.form.markAsPristine();
}

submitButtonEnabled(): boolean {
  return this.form.valid
    && this.form.dirty;
}
```

p.s. this is an `Edit Form`, so there will always be values in the initial state for all fields. So when the form has first loaded both fields (email and username) are valid, and one of them changes it will trigger the AsyncValidator, and if the response is true, `submitButtonEnabled` should return true.

Answer (score 0):

A AsyncValidator is some more easy than your code. (really you can not use the valueChanges observable).

Imagine you has a dataService with two functions that return an observable true if exist and false if not. Well, I simulate by using "of" rxjs operator and delay

```
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }
  emails=['qqq@qqq.com','aaa@aaa.com']
  userNames=['qqq','aaa','bbb']
  existEmail(email:string)
  {
   return of(this.emails.indexOf(email)>=0?true:false).pipe(delay (1000))
  }
  existUser(userName:string)
  {
   return of(this.userNames.indexOf(userName)>=0?true:false).pipe(delay (1000))
  }
}
```

You can create a form like

```
form=new FormGroup( {
    name:new FormControl('',{asyncValidators:this.uniqueName(),updateOn:'blur'}),
    email:new FormControl('',{asyncValidators:this.uniqueEmail(),updateOn:'blur'}),
  })
  uniqueName()
  {
    return (control:FormControl)=>{
       return this.dataService.existUser(control.value).pipe(map(x=>
       {
         return x?{error:'yet exist'}:null
       }))
    }
  }
  uniqueEmail()
  {
    return (control:FormControl)=>{
       return this.dataService.existEmail(control.value).pipe(map(x=>
       {
         return x?{error:'yet exist'}:null
       }))
    }
  }
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnkzz1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Take account:

1. I use {updateOn:'blur'} to only check when blur
2. The validators return an Observable, in case error an
   observable of an object {error:'yet exist'}, in case valid an
   observable of null.
3. As from the dataService you receive true -if exist- or false -if not- I use (pipe(map) to transform the response, and use 'of' rxjs to return the observable

If you want use a delay becaouse you dn't like the {updateOn:'blur'} I suggest that use tro auxiliars formControls

```
control1=new FormControl()
control2=new formControl()
form=new FormGroup( {
        name:new FormControl('',{asyncValidators:this.uniqueName()}),
        email:new FormControl('',{asyncValidators:this.uniqueEmail()}),
      })

this.control1.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(res=>{
          this.form.get('name').setValue(res)
      })

this.control2.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(res=>{
          this.form.get('email').setValue(res)
      })
```

You not use the form, you use

```
<input [formControl]="control1">
<input [formControl]="control2">
```

Comment: It seems like the `valueChanges` was the one causing this. What I did was just put that `if(value === originalValue)` outside the pipe (in `UniqueValidatorByFunction` level) and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if (!control.valueChanges) {
    return of(null as ValidationErrors);
  }

  if (!obs) {
    obs =  merge(
      of(control.value),
      control.valueChanges
    ).pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((login: string) => {
        ...
      }),
      map(_ => {
        return id == null ?
          null :
          { exists: true };
      })
    );
  }

  return obs.pipe(first());
```